# How to accept comma separated list as one parameter in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I currently have a batch file that takes in a few parameters and passes them as variables to a configuration file. One of the parameters is a path to log files.

The configuration file accepts the variable from the batch file as follows:

```
path => "${LOGFILE}"
```

If I were to specify the paths directly in the configuration file it would be accepted as follows:

```
path => [ "/dir1/dir2/*.log", "/dir3/dir4/*.log"
```

Here is the batch code for the param "-logfile" which echos as %LOGFILE%:

```
IF "%~1"=="-logfile" (
   IF NOT EXIST "%~2" (
      echo "**********************"
      echo "ERROR: Log file %~2 does not exist. Exiting"
      goto exit
      ) ELSE (
         ::
         :: Convert to unix format... that's what logstash expects
         ::
     set LOGTEMP=%~2
     set LOGFILE=!LOGTEMP:\=/!
```

My goal is to be able to type a command like

```
my_batfile -logfile /dir1/dir2/*.log, /dir3/dir4/*.log -nextarg blahblahblah
```

Currently when I try this, the batch file recognizes the comma and separates the paths.

I hope I have made this clear enough, sorry for any confusion.

---

EDIT

---

With quotations around the paths the batch file DOES recognize the paths as one string. However, now that it is one string, it cannot verify that those paths exists so it produces an error.

I think now what I need to do is be able to loop through the list for each path but pass them as one variable to the configuration file. Another bump in this road is that the number of paths may not always be the same.

If anyone has any suggestions on a different way to reach this goal that would be much appreciated as well!

Thank you for your help!
- Miranda

Comment: One way would be to add them without `,` and then just build a join in the batch file to join `%~2` and `%~3` with a comma.

Comment: also have you tried enclosing the paths in quotes? `my_batfile -logfile "/dir1/dir2/*.log, /dir3/dir4/*.log" -nextarg blahblahblah`

Comment: So I tried using the quotations and I think it accomplished what I originally asked for, so thank you! :) But now I a new error has arose. I will add it to my original post.

Comment: then we need to go back to the original comment. Pass the paths sepecrated by whitespace and verify each, then once verified join them in the script with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can parse your parameters. I'm sure, you can insert your "workload" yourself

```
@echo off & setlocal 

IF "%~1"=="-logfile" call :parse %~2
if "%~3"=="-nextarg" call :parse %~4
goto :eof

:parse
if "%~1" == "" goto :eof
echo %~1
shift
goto :parse
```

try it with:

```
my_batfile -logfile "/dir1/dir2/*.log, /dir3/dir4/*.log" -nextarg "blahblahblah,blublublub,bliblibli
```

The called subroutine has it's "own" parameters `%<n>` independent of the "main" parameters. So `%1` in the subroutine isn't the same as `%1` from the original parameters, but the first parameter *given to the subroutine*.

Remaining problem: you can't use paths containing spaces (`""path with space","path2 with spaces""` wouldn't parse correct)